# Renaming columns within a Select SQL

Tags: sql, json, odbc

I am having issues with renaming columns within a select.

Here is the original SQL command

```
SELECT 
"id",
"1",
"3_3",
"3_6",
"4",
"5",
"6"
FROM "entries_without_parent" WITH( meta='TileTech_Meta_For_Contact_Forms' )
```

Here is the command I tried

```
SELECT 
"id",
"1",
FROM "entries_without_parent" WITH( meta='TileTech_Meta_For_Contact_Forms' ),
Select 
"3_3", 
"3_6" as 'FullName'
FROM "entries_without_parent" WITH( meta='TileTech_Meta_For_Contact_Forms' ),

SELECT
"4",
"5",
"6"

FROM "entries_without_parent" WITH( meta='TileTech_Meta_For_Contact_Forms' )
```

I need to merge 3_3 and 3_6 and call it Full Name

but then I would like to also rename all the columns into something that isn't a number like 1 to Email.

I am fairly new to SQL but I've gotten this fair, to say the least.

The original command works but when I tried to modify the SQL command I get errors such as this one

```
Ln3. col 98: Syntax error. expected: CONNECTION.).UNION.:
```

Send help!

Comment: As the information hovering the `sql` tag says, add a tag for the DB that you are using.

Comment: @PaulT. Can you show me? Sorry, I don't understand this syntax as much.

Comment: ? ... add a tag for your DB? `mysql`, `oracle`, `mssql` ... etc.? Simply edit the question and add the relative tag for the DB that you use, as you did for the `sql` and `json` tags.

Comment: @PaulT. Sorry I read that comment wrong

Comment: `ODBC` is not a database, but a connectivity protocol that many DB's can use. What DB are you using with ODBC? ... it has to be one of the DB vendors: MS Access, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle, etc.

Comment: I dont know what it is. all I know is that I am trying to connect a rest API to an ODBC gateway. my client doesnt have MS ACCESS or anything like that. but since its a windows machine lets say access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you that the numeric column names on that table are the pits.

You wrote

```
SELECT "3_3", 
       "3_6" AS 'FullName'
FROM "entries_without_parent" ...
```

(Well, you wrote several SELECTs, but let's just stick to one,
and avoid any UNION ALL craziness.)

I don't recognize that WITH meta syntax,
and you didn't specify which DB vendor you're using,
so I'm just going to ignore it and go with SQL-92.

You are using quoting I do not recognize, such as `"3_6"`.
I will ignore that, and will prefer the standard backtick quoting
for column names that don't start with alpha, that don't look
like an identifier. Note that some vendors use `[` `]` square brackets
to quote such column names.

Use this:

```
SELECT `id`,
       `3_3` AS first_name,
       `3_6` AS last_name
FROM entries_without_parent ...
```

The two-character `id` actually needs no quoting, as it looks
like an alphanumeric identifier that starts with alpha, starts with `i`.
I just quoted it for consistency -- feel free to strip those spurious quotes.

---

Additionally, you wish to combine certain columns.
Use this:

```
SELECT id,
       CONCAT(`3_3`, " ", `3_6`) AS full_name ...
```

Some DB vendors let you catenate strings with vertical bar notation:

```
SELECT id,
       `3_3` || " " || `3_6` AS full_name ...
```

I invite you to [Read The Fine Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am going to try this later and will let you know my results!

Comment: Confirmed! I was able to rename the columns! thank you @J_H